# Проблемы с сервером: после обработки запроса сервер не может прочитать с сокета и писать в сокет

Tags: сокеты, php, сервер

Доброго времени суток! есть у меня сервер:

```
   <?php
        set_time_limit(0);

        ob_implicit_flush();

        $adress = 'localhost';

        $port = 1985;

        if(($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) < 0)
        {
            die('socket create error');
        }

        if(($ret = socket_bind($sock, $adress, $port)) < 0)
        {
            die('socket bind error');
        }

        //максимум 10 одновременных соединений
        if(($ret = socket_listen($sock, 10)) < 0)
        {
            die('socket listen error'); 
        }

        do
        {
            //принимаем соединение с сокетом
            if(($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) < 0)
            {
                die('socket connect error');
            }

            $msg = 'server ready';
            socket_write($msgsock,$msg,strlen($msg));

            //бесконечный цикл ожидания клиентов
            do
            {
                if(false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 1024)))
                {
                    echo 'read message error';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo $buf;
                }
                $resp = '';

                $buf = json_decode($buf,true);
                if($buf['client'] == 'site')
                {
                    if($buf['task'] == 'analise')
                    {
                        $resp = 'task accepted';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $resp = 'unknown task';
                    }                           
                }
                else
                {
                    $resp = 'unknown task';
                }

                if($buf['task'] == 'exit')
                {
                    socket_close($msgsock);
                    break;
                }

            socket_write($msgsock, $resp, strlen($resp));   
            }while(true);
        }while(true);
        if(isset($sock))
        {
            socket_close($sock);
            echo 'socket closed';
        }
    ?>
```

проблема в том, что иногда после обработки запроса от клиента сервер выводит сообщения что не может прочитать с сокета и писать в сокет. В чем может быть проблема? Клиентский сокет закрывается нормально

Comment: Не помню где, но еще нужно учитывать размер передаваемого сообщения. По умолчанию там кажется 64 байта.

Comment: strlen($resp) - размер передаваемого сообщения